# Let's think of a creative name for our chatroom

Tags: discussion, chat

The chatroom name is so bland. "Lifehacks." Look at all the creative names others have thought up:

- "Root Access" for Super User
- "The DMZ" for Security
- "The Renderfarm" for Blender
- "The Litter Box" for Pets
- "The Hangar" for Aviation
- "You Are Here" for Travel
- "The Water Cooler" for The Workplace
- "The Whiteboard" for Programmers
- "The Nineteenth Byte" for Code Golf
- etc...

Can we think of a better name for our chatroom?

Only one idea per answer, please. Vote up the ideas that you like!

<sup>Stolen from [PPCG meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1005/3808). But that's okay, because I wrote that post too. :P</sup>

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about **"The Junk Drawer"**

You know, that drawer that every person in the world has, where all the weird and wonderful things that aren't currently useful get stored, because you know they might be some day!

Typically this is the drawer where you will find the radiator bleeding key alongside a charger for a device that you can't even remember owning

Comment: I really like this!

Comment: I like the sound of this, +1! ....offshoot answer: http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/46/59 ( *for those of you who don't like the sound of "junk"* )

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RgUpDGAIdds

Answer (score 8):

**MacGyver's Place**

Fairly self explanatory, I think.

Comment: I'd call it "MacGyvering" but basically its the same idea.

Answer (score 6):

Can we just call it "Chat"? That seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking for more of a creativ- oh. Oh, I see what you did there.

Comment: If we can get this through, it would actually be a nice hack.

Answer (score 2):

As an offshoot of [Adi's suggestion](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/a/39/59), how about

**The Odds and Ends Drawer**

.....same idea, but avoids the negative connotation of the word "junk."

( *I wouldn't want to tell my friends that I hang out in a junk drawer....says something about a person* :P )

Answer (score 1):

How about "Duct tape and paperclips"...

Comment: This isn't really a *place* so much as an object though.

Comment: Maybe "Held together by duct tape and paperclips"? ....still more of an adjective than a place, but that could be improved on, perhaps.

Comment: @Door same applies for the nineteenth byte... or the whiteboard.. or (depending on interpretation) the 2nd monitor....

Comment: @Vogel612 "The Nineteenth Byte" is a reference to a typical name of a club near the end of a golf course ("The Nineteenth Hole"). "The Whiteboard" is a place that you could typically meet at (ex. "Let's discuss this at the whiteboard"). However, this idea just seems to be a collection of objects.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Tinkering Basement'

Since we tinker with stuff sometimes... and at least I do that in my basement

Answer (score 0):

**"Tinker Well"**

We like to tinker and we do it well.

Answer (score 0):

**"Tinker Hell"**

This is where the tinkerers go :)

Answer (score -1):

**"Lifehackers"** - Not the most creative name, but still a better name than "Lifehacks".

Answer (score -2):

Hacked to Pieces

..................