# "I have problem X. I would try solution Y, but I can't because of Z"

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

Given the new scope [here](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1217/59), that says (in part) that

> **If the question is not looking for an alternative to a product or solution that they have tried, then that question is off-topic on this
>   site.** Because a lifehack is an alternative to a solution or product
>   that is unavailable or undesirable, we need to know what product or
>   solution they are trying to work around. Unfortunately, this will
>   probably leave some questions without a site to be asked on, but we
>   simply can not take every question if we expect to have any sort of
>   quality control.

What about a question that asks

> I have problem *X*. I would try solution *Y*, but I can't because of *Z*.

Does that *Y* count as a "solution that they have tried"? ( *and, by extension, would a well-formulated Z count as sufficient explanation?* )

Comment: in a hack context the lack of Z is often the reason a hack is needed. Like I don't have a hammer, how do I drive a nail, Answer use another heavy tool like a pipe wrench..

Answer (score 8):

I think that a question like that does fit the new scope, because it acknowledges that a "standard" option does exist, but can't be used because it is (in the wording of the scope question) "unavailable."

So long as "*Z*" is well-explained (he's [camping](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/463/59), and doesn't have access to a whetstone or knife steel; his [shaver broke](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/1806/59), and he can't use a razor/sharp knife for religious reasons), my opinion is that the question would be squarely on-topic on LH according to the new scope.

Comment: Provided that the question shows that they have put forth thought into a solution and provide reason behind why that solution doesn't work, I agree with this

Comment: What about I just don't have access to the standard item (is this on topic)?  http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/421/how-do-i-open-a-bottle-without-a-bottle-opener/426#426