# Let's make this clear: this site is **not** the same as Lifehacker

Tags: discussion, scope

[Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/) is a cool website -- you can find how-to articles on just about anything from kitchen to computing. I've used it a bunch of times to help me figure out how to do several things with my computer, for example.

However, even though our site has a similar name, ***our scope is NOT the same as that of Lifehacker.***

Our site (for the moment) only takes questions about [*physical problems*](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1217/59), for example. Therefore, questions about booting Ubuntu are off-topic, *even though you might find the answer at Lifehacker*.*

This is not to say that I think that questions involving tech are off-topic; a question about [cleaning a dirty computer screen](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/166/59), for example, is on-topic.

I don't either mean to say that anything found on Lifehacker is off-topic; like I said, they also have solutions to "real-life, physical problems," such as [one](http://lifehacker.com/hone-a-knife-with-black-and-white-newspaper-1677129363) or [two](http://lifehacker.com/5479413/sharpen-your-kitchen-knife-on-a-coffee-mug) alternate methods for sharpening knives.

---

* <sup>We have other sites that serve this purpose: [Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/), [Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/), [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), and a few others.</sup>

Answer (score 13):

I agree with this very much. However, I don't think that something is off-topic just because it is on-topic on another SE site, inclusive of computer issues.

For example, if I'm looking for a hack to keep a child from deleting my files, it could be on-topic at either of the following:

- Super User
- Parenting

not to mention the platform-specific sites:

- Android
- Ask Different
- Ask Ubuntu
- Unix & Linux
- Web Apps (If the files are in Google Drive, OneDrive, etc.)

A valid "hack" for this answer may be to cover the keyboard and mouse, whilst other sites would take a software-based approach.

This comes back to questions being on-topic based on their end-points. This means a lot of NAA's and vaguely closed questions.

Comment: Oh, I agree with this entirely. Do you think that this was unclear in my question?

Comment: @Shokhet "We have other sites that serve this purpose"

Comment: ....I meant that footnote as just a "Hey, if you're disappointed that your question couldn't be handled here, you can ask it [over here](http://example.com)

Comment: @Shokhet +1 But the issue of endpoint-based closure still exists.

Comment: I was planning on raising that on Meta at some point; perhaps I will. You can do that yourself if you think it's a big problem.

Comment: @Shokhet Writing it up now.

Comment: Awesome! Waiting to upvote. ...please use the term [ipso facto](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ipso_facto) in the title; I'd love to link to the post using that term :)

Comment: @Shokhet http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/2405/15