# How elaborate is an on-topic hack?

Tags: discussion, scope

*Inspired by [this question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/3992/15) and [this chat message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20196651#20196651).*

One example is that [Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255019/1234256). Although we *are* a hack-writing service, so to speak, how elaborate can such a hack be?

Questions asking "how to make..." such as [this one](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/5540/15) and [this one](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/3848/15) are closed, because [we aren't Lifehacker](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2403/15). I also believe [this question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/3992/15) falls into the same category, but since [some disagree](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20196651#20196651), I think this needs to be part of the scope, one way or the other.

They *are* all looking for hacks, but we do agree they are off-topic because they are asking for too much. At the very least, I very much hope every person reading this agrees that

- "How do I build a table and chairs from a pile of wood?"

is off-topic. Thank you for reading all that.

Comment: Yes, a bit too much.

Comment: The intent in "we are not Lifehacker" was about the software part of tech questions, specifically; not about making things.

Comment: @Shokhet I understand that's the point your post makes, but the same thing applies, imo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with you that the questions about how to build or make something, like the [Anti-RSI Workstation question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/3992/anti-rsi-ergonomic-workstation), are off-topic. As you (and that meta post) said, we aren't Lifehacker. I think we should put in our scope that questions about making something are not for this website. They can go to [Engineering.SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) or some other SE site, but here we are looking for questions that are everyday problems. These are too elaborate, as they are usually building projects which require long answers, which I don't believe we are a site for.

Answer (score 1):

I challenged the poster of the Anti-RSI Workstation saying it represents a project. A project might be more than a simple hack. But some hacks do require time and meticulousness. When a question is better represented as a project than a hack, comparing the two, then maybe it's out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

I think that, as long as the question presents a problem (still gotta be physical) that needs a solution, it's on topic.

That anti-RSI may be falling prey (a little) to the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56366/266359). Perhaps a better way to approach question posts of problems where you think you have an answer is to post your answer *as an answer*, and let people vote and comment on the feasibility, and then be able to suggest other solutions as their own answers.

Comment: When doing business analysis and working with users this is very true.